# using jquery check the corresponding checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to jquery question...

Using jQuery, depending on the radio button clicked I would like jQuery auto 'check' the corresponding checkbox.

```
<input type="radio" value="#ID#" name="#ID#1" 
       onclick="return tickSession(this);"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="#ID#" id="#ID#" 
       name="sessionsThatNeedBookingOnto" class="#ID#1"/>

<input type="radio" value="#ID#" name="#ID#1" 
       onclick="return tickSession(this);"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="#ID#" id="#ID#" 
       name="sessionsThatNeedBookingOnto" class="#ID#1"/>
```

```
<input type="radio" value="#ID#" name="#ID#2" 
       onclick="return tickSession(this);"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="#ID#" id="#ID#" 
       name="sessionsThatNeedBookingOnto" class="#ID#2"/>
```

This is what I have tried but my understanding is a little off...

```
<script>
    function tickSession(elementHere){
            alert($(elementHere).val());
            $(elementHere).attr('id').attr("checked", "true");
            $($(elementHere).val()).attr('checked','checked')

    }
  </script>
```

Comment: one more thing . your naming convention is wrong for id's .       Naming rules:

    Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
    Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")
    In HTML, all values are case-insensitive

Comment: They are technically valid in HTML5, but the pound signs must be escaped in the jQuery selector statement so it parses correctly.  However, **IDs must be unique**.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rework your checkboxes/radios:

```
<input type="radio" value="#ID#" name="rd1" class='rd-session-control'/>
<input type="checkbox" value="#ID#" id="for-rd1" 
    name="sessionsThatNeedBookingOnto" class="#ID#1"/>
```

Now:

```
$(function() {
    $('.rd-session-control').click(function() {
        var checkbox = $('#for-' + $(this).attr('id'));
        if (checkbox.is(':checked'))
            checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
        else
            checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
});
```

What this does is:

1. Allow you to set all of the click handlers for the radios at once using a class `rd-session-control`.
2. The ID attribute for the checkboxes is sane and easily calculated relative to the radio that controls them.
3. Uses the `:checked` selector to test if the checkbox is active or not.

Comment: alert($(this).attr('id')); give me undefined with you example. the radio box does not have an id

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('input:radio').click(function(){

      $(this).next('checkbox').attr('checked',true);
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: for this to work I would need to know what the checkbox was called right? this gets passed in with the function i think so does input radio need to be $(elementHere).val()? as the value of the radio is the id of the checkbox

Comment: @Spark , no that is not needed . when you click a radio button , it automatically takses the checkbox by $(this).next('checkbox') . your clicked radio button is $(this) you can get any check box attribute checked by that way .